# Application Stress Test Error

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am stress testing my application and have written a simple test to spawn hundreds of threads that call a method.
The code below works fine for 1000 threads and 100 ms delay.

In the code below when the number of threads is 2000 and the delay is 100 i get the error
Cannot load the "shell32.dll" DLL into memory in the catch statement for radButtonEmptyThread_Click

1. How do i fix this?
2. The value written "Debug.Print(count.ToString());" is always 1000 - why?

**C# Code**

```
private void radButtonEmptyThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxWaitThreads.Text); i++)
                {
                    Thread Trd = new Thread(() => EmptyThreadRequest(int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodDelay.Text), i));
                    Trd.IsBackground = true;
                    Trd.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

            }
        }

        private void EmptyThreadRequest(int delay, int count)
        {

            try
            {

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
                Debug.Print(count.ToString());


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stop creating so many threads. That's very resource-intensive. Instead, use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx).
2. `i` is a [captured variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271440/785745), which means the threads all access the original variable, not a copy. If you create a copy of the variable inside the loop, it will work as expected.

Comment: @Ameen I'm guessing it's because the OS can't handle that many threads at once.

Comment: if i use tasks will i not get the error - what about Ameens very valid question? 2. makes sense but what is the solution here?

Comment: I don't think Tasks will cause a problem. They use pooled threads.

Comment: only one way to find out. ill report back - what about item 2.?

Comment: Edited. Also, see the linked question.

Comment: @KendallFrey, that's my guess too, but I would have liked to see some explanation as to how in the hell that would translate into a module load error. user1438082, you can also use Thread.QueueUserWorkItem and that would also be a lot more efficient than creating a new thread for every single call.

Comment: I doubt I'll be able to explain it much better, since I didn't write Windows, and am not an expert on how it handles threads.

Comment: hi, see my answer posted for 1. - is this ok? it works for 40000 threads and a delay of 100 ms - i noticed the number of threads it creates in the resource monitor does not go above 41 - the original post was at ~1100. make sense?

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the captured variable issue, inside the loop do this:

```
int x = i;
Thread Trd = new Thread(() => EmptyThreadRequest(int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodDelay.Text), x));
```

And of course, consider using Tasks.

2000 is a functional limit enforced by Windows. I think it might have something to do with minimum stack allocated to each thread, but I would not bet my life on it. Tasks are very light weight threads, prefer them over threads when possible.

Answer (score -1):

**C# Code**

```
private void radButtonCallEmptyTasks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxWaitThreads.Text); i++)
        {

            // Create a task and supply a user delegate by using a lambda expression. 
            var taskA = new Task(() => EmptyTaskRequest(int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodDelay.Text), i));
            // Start the task.
            taskA.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

    }
}



private void EmptyTaskRequest(int delay, int count)
{

    try
    {

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
        Debug.Print(count.ToString());


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

    }
}
```

}